# Are all pink bags anti static?

Tags: esd, antistatic

I was shipped a USB dongle in a small pink baggie.  If it's an anti-static bag I would love to re-use it.  How sure can I be that it is, and is there a way to test it?

Comment: Usually the pink ones are only dissipative

Comment: See [EEVblog #247 - Anti Static Bag Myth Revisted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imdtXcnywb8) for a full discussion about about how bags work. In a nutshell, a pink bag won't *generate* static charges, but it will NOT *protect against external charges*.

Comment: Pink is dissipative & VERY quickly loses its ability to protect static-sentitive devices. DO NOT USE PINK BAGS

Comment: I was under the impression that the pink bags are "anti-static" in the sense that they don't *generate* static electricity. If you want real anti-static (static-shielding) bags you really need the good silver-colored ones. EDIT: I just noticed that Dave Tweed already said this....

Answer (score 2):

If you ask the Jet Propulsion Lab (JPL) then 'No'. Pink PP bags have a very thin layer of "ESD" coating that is easy to rub off, and then your left with plastic which isn't good. At a place I worked we could only use them for shipping and then never again.

I'll quote the [document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiy68adsITLAhVE5WMKHWPDD0wQFggrMAI&url=ftp%3A%2F%2Fapollo.ssl.berkeley.edu%2Fpub%2FME_Archives%2FGovernment%2520and%2520Industry%2520Standards%2FNASA%2520Documents%2FJPL-D1348_Rev_F%2520JPL%27s%2520ESD%2520practice.doc&usg=AFQjCNGfgtNd5qLDxAHbYniqQxG5b2TNDA&sig2=IcUWO6MS8Ckj5G519LDfEQ) (if that link goes down you could probably find it [here](https://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Search&q=pink%20bags%20anti%20static%20esd%20training%20jpl)):

From Standard: Electrostatic Discharge Control (JPL-D1348_Rev_F)

If you try and test it with a multimeter you may be rubbing the layer off.

> 2.3.30    Pink-Polyethylene (pink-poly)
>
> The use of pink-poly bags, film, bubble-wrap or foam near any ESDS
>   item or within an ESD protected area is prohibited. Pink-poly provides
>   little protection against ESD events and voltage fields and is a
>   contamination source. The preferred alternative is the metalized
>   static-shielding bag.

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking alligator clips & multimeter leads to the bag.

Good anti-static bags should have some measurable conductivity (i.e. resistance less than infinity/err on your meter).

Comment: Have you actually tried this? What kind of values did you get? I'm not getting anything even on the 20 Mohm settings on my meters, while testing a range of anti-static bags from different suppliers.

Comment: I don't have any handy right now, but have gotten reading of several Kohm in the past, from closely spaced leads/clips. Also, @DaveTweed posted a youTub vid where the (annoying) narrator demonstrates exactly this with a 'mylar' metallized esd bag.

Comment: The mylar bags and the black conductive ESD foam will read some resistance on a multimeter.  The pink bags have a static dissipative coating, but in my experience it's not conductive to the point where you could measure a resistance on an ohmmeter.

Comment: For what it's worth, I checked some pink foam and the conductivity was less than 0.1nS, so more than 10G\$\Omega\$